# Use a variable with "LIKE %" (e.g. "variable%") in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

The question is similar to using **LIKE** in **SQL *PLUS**, where a select statement contains a **LIKE** clause as follows:

```
select * from sometable where somecolumn LIKE 'something%';
```

How could one use the same within a cursor? I tried using the following:

```
 cursor c is select * from sometable where somecolumn like 'something%';
```

*same as above*

EDIT: I need to get **something** as a parameter, meaning, the select statement is executed within a stored procedure.

**EDIT 2:**

```
create procedure proc1 (search VARCHAR) is

cursor c is select student_name from students where student_name like 'search%';
```

--I know using 'search%' retrieves student names containing 'the key search', but is there any other way to use such a variable.

```
do something;

end;
```

In short, I need to select student names containing a value that is passed as a parameter; this may not be the whole name, and may suffice enough to be used within a like clause.

Comment: So ... you tried it ... and *what happened*?

Comment: Are you sure *that's* the cause? `CURSOR x IS {select}` should be valid, where `{select}` represents an arbitrary select DQL.

Comment: I get a variable, **something** as a parameter, and use it within the cursor.

Comment: Please post a *full* (but minimal) context illustrating the error that others can *try*. I believe there is an important part missing in this simplification. `'something%'` is just a literal; no variables involved.

Comment: The post and reported error message and intent do not align. I have updated the title to give it some direction. No point worrying about a CURSOR until you are able to do it with a "normal" SELECT.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As per my understanding to your issue, you are using variable `search` within quotes. Put your variable outside the quotes, e.g.:

```
 create or replace procedure PROC1(search VARCHAR2) 
 IS
  cursor test_cur(search IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
    SELECT student_name 
    FROM student
    WHERE student_name LIKE search||'%'; --you're putting you variable within quotes

 v_temp_var student.student_name%TYPE;

BEGIN

 OPEN test_cur(search);
  LOOP
   FETCH test_cur INTO v_temp_var;
    EXIT WHEN test_cur%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_temp_var);  
  END LOOP;

 CLOSE test_cur;

END test;
```