# How to use a variable in a LIKE clause in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle and learning; I am simply trying to run this T-SQL query

```
DECLARE @SearchObj varchar(100);
SET @SearchObj='%aldbrough%';

SELECT
      obj_id,
      name,
      description
   FROM
      agnis.t_object
   WHERE
      lower(name) = ObjToSearch ;
```

I am using SQL Developer Oracle tool which also have a "Scratch Editor" to help with translation from T-SQL. When i run the tool it gave me this code

```
     DECLARE
   v_SearchObj VARCHAR2(100);

    BEGIN
       v_SearchObj := '%aldbrough%' ;
       SELECT obj_id ,
              NAME ,
              DESCRIPTION 
         FROM agnis.t_object 
        WHERE  LOWER(NAME) = ObjToSearch;

    END;
```

but the same tool give me this error

```
    Error report -
ORA-06550: line 10, column 26:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "OBJTOSEARCH": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 6, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

so what is the correct syntax to use a variable into a LIKE clause that returns multiple rows?
I hope I do not have to use cursors etc for such of a simple statement as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150723/use-a-variable-with-like-e-g-variable-in-pl-sql)

Comment: As for your other point, you don't have to use an explicit cursor. But you do have to select the result set into **something**. As your query returns multiple rows [you should use an array](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_C3WO8BUQ7WYBOE21UQ6ZZN91R.html). Unless you're using 12c or higher, in which case you can use T-SQL style implicit cursors, but there's still more coding than there is in T-SQL. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1)

Comment: Thanks and apolgies for the = instead of LIKE etc. that is my bad habit to copy and paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes - those "translators" don't always do what they are supposed to.

This is how your code should look like:

- use `like`, not `=` in the `where` clause
- in PL/SQL, you have to put the result of the `select` statement `into` something - for example, locally declared variables (as my example shows).

So:

```
DECLARE
   v_SearchObj    VARCHAR2 (100) := '%aldbrough%';
   --
   v_obj_id       t_object.obj_id%TYPE;
   v_name         t_object.name%TYPE;
   v_description  t_object.description%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT obj_id, NAME, DESCRIPTION
     INTO v_obj_id, v_name, v_description
     FROM agnis.t_object
    WHERE LOWER (NAME) LIKE v_searchobj;
END;
```

---

If such a code returns an error - `too_many_rows` (and yes, it does), then one option is to *loop* through rows and *do something* (such as display those values):

```
DECLARE
   v_SearchObj  VARCHAR2 (100) := '%aldbrough%';
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT obj_id, NAME, DESCRIPTION
                   FROM agnis.t_object
                  WHERE LOWER (NAME) LIKE v_searchobj)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Name = ' || cur_r.name || ', description = ' || cur_r.description);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Ok I see that I have to declare a variable for each data item returned from my query but yes, in this case, using your good code is giving me an error for returning multiple rows

Comment: Exactly, just like @APC has said. I added some more code which shows how you might "fix" that, but - the final result depends on what you want to do. This just displays values in a tool that supports DBMS_OUTPUT (such as SQLPlus or SQL Developer).

Comment: I am now using this code 

DECLARE
  v_SearchObj    VARCHAR2 (100) := '%aldbrough%';  
  
  TYPE v_obj_id      IS TABLE OF       NUMBER;
  TYPE v_name        IS TABLE OF       VARCHAR(200);
  TYPE v_description IS TABLE OF       VARCHAR(200);

BEGIN
   SELECT obj_id, NAME, DESCRIPTION
     BULK COLLECT INTO v_obj_id, v_name, v_description
     FROM agnis.t_object
    WHERE LOWER (NAME) LIKE v_searchobj;
END;

but I get this error
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 24:
PLS-00321: expression 'V_OBJ_ID' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Comment: You can't format code in comments; it is better to edit the original question you posted. Anyway, you can't bulk collect 3 columns into 3 arrays. Create one array which will contain all 3 columns.

Comment: @brillox You can `BULK COLLECT` 3 columns into 3 arrays [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=92b65ceddd65905afca5ac3c57219d1d). You just need to declare the collections as variables as well as declaring the types for those collections. And you can write code by wrapping it in ` backticks but you can't include line breaks in comments.

Comment: You can? Cool, never tried that. Didn't have to. Nice, thank you, @MT0!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged SQL Developer, use a bind variable:

```sql
SELECT obj_id,
       name,
       description
FROM   agnis.t_object
WHERE  lower(name) = :ObjToSearch;
```

and SQL developer will pop up a dialog box where you can set the value of the `ObjToSearch` variable.

If you want to specify the bind variable in code then:

```sql
VARIABLE objtosearch VARCHAR2(50)

BEGIN
  :objtosearch := '%aldbrough%';
END;
/

SELECT obj_id,
       name,
       description
FROM   agnis.t_object
WHERE  lower(name) = :ObjToSearch;
```

And run the statements as a script using <kbd>F5</kbd> rather than as individual statements.